# What is the correct way to use multiple variables in a Text element?

Tags: react-native, eslint

I can't seem to find the "correct" way to use multiple variables in a React Native Text element.
I have the users first, and the last name as separate object values and I want to show them in the same Text element.

```
<Text>{props.user.firstName} {props.user.lastName}</Text>
```

This works fine, but ESLint doesn't like it. (jsx-one-expression-per-line).
If I put them on separate lines, then I can't figure out where to put the empty space in between first and last name.

```
<Text>
  {props.user.firstName} 
  {props.user.lastName}
</Text>
```

There's an empty space after {props.user.firstName}, but ESLint doesn't like that either (no-trailing-spaces).

So I'm asking whether there is a correct way to achieve the result that I want without changing ESLint configuration or creating a separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
You can nest your variables like so:

`` <Text>`${props.user.firstName} ${props.user.lastName}`</Text> ``